# Why did the Vikings stop raiding Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, vikings

Was it because of their defeats by Alfred and the settlement of Normandy?
Were there issues at home which changed their focus?

I did search through quite a few of the questions on here, but did not see this addressed.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  Google provided [hurstwic](https://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/society/text/what_happened.htm#:~:text=A%20better%20question%20to%20ask,where%20the%20raids%20took%20place.) and [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/question/Why-did-Viking-raids-stop)

Comment: The _What if they had Not stopped?_ part of the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Shame. This is actually a super astute question IMHO. You can often learn a lot more about a thing by turning it around like this.

Comment: agree - its a good question that i'd never considered. Well done to OP

Comment: "In Scandinavia, the Viking Age is considered to have ended with the establishment of royal authority in the Scandinavian countries and the establishment of Christianity as the dominant religion." ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_Age))

Comment: @Tomas By's point is on target, but it really documents the end of a process of the Scandinavian countries *becoming* countries with effective governments, a process in which they lagged some behind other European countries. Would-be kings supported the Church as a unifying influence and the Church supported the kings as civilizing influences...and neither found the Vikings to be a useful part of their society. Add to that the growing power of the Vikings' targets and going a Viking ceased to be an economically viable lifestyle.

Comment: While @TomasBy 's point is valid - it ignores target changes, namely hardening of defenses, that earlier Viking raids enforced on the remnants of the Carolingian Empire. In turn Viking raids escalate in size: progressively larger forces seeking progressively larger targets: First whole counties (Normandy and perhaps also Picardy); then whole countries (Canute, Harold Hardrada and William); Sicily and Southern Italy; and finally the Holy Land in the First Crusade (At least 3 of the 4 main Crusader armies was substantially Norman in both composition and leadership.)

Comment: So even as the Viking Ear is winding down around the North Sea in the early to mid-11th Century, it is continuing around the Mediterranean Basin for at least another couple of generations; but upped in scale another notch in size of both forces and targets.

Answer (score 4):

A gradual diminishing of the factors that drove vikings to raid, as well as opportunities for successful raiding.

## Why did the Vikings raid in the first place?

Vikings did not go far from home and risk their lives for the fun of it. There are many theories, and likely many overlapping factors, that caused the beginning of the Viking raids. For example:

- [Gender imbalance](https://www.sciencealert.com/vikings-might-have-raided-because-there-was-a-shortage-of-single-women) - in a polygynous society, with each man of status expected to have several concubines, there are obviously not going to be enough to go around without raiding.
- [Economic imbalance](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10814-021-09163-3) - at the beginning of the Viking Age, Scandinavia was not a very rich society. Once maritime technology allowed them to access the [wealth](https://sites.google.com/view/viking-silver/about-the-project) of the lands plugged into the Mediterranean system of trade, it was a better way to make money than staying home.

## So why might they have stopped?

- They were successful! A gradual trickle of spoils back to Scandinavia (or settling of "surplus sons" elsewhere in Europe) and the damage inflicted on the economies being raided shifted the economic and gender imbalances closer towards an equilibrium. Raiding became much less necessary.
- Integration of the Norse into Christian Europe - Viking chiefs were happy to get wealth without the risk of raiding. They would increasingly be paid off, such as in the case of [Sweyn Estridsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweyn_II_of_Denmark#Consolidation_of_power) or [granted rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollo) of European land. Scandinavia would eventually unify itself under three Christian kingdoms, putting an end to warlordism that both created warriors & encouraged them to leave and seek a more peaceful land, relieving the pressure to raid for women, and reducing the acceptability of raiding. As former vikings spread into Europe, they also gained opportunities for a steady salary as part of a mercenary army (this is how the Norman conquest of [Sicily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_southern_Italy) began).
- Lack of targets - Atlantic coastlines [fortified](https://acoup.blog/2021/12/10/collections-fortification-part-iii-castling/) themselves, allowing the wealth of the land to be protected against raiding. Local rulers were able to organize an [effective response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogad_G%C3%A1edel_re_Gallaib) to viking settlers. Norway [took the opportunity to raid England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eystein_II_of_Norway) when it presented itself, but this would be the last such raid.

Answer (score -2):

Three main factors have played to stop the series of raids that have happened during the High Middle Age:

- First factor: Reinforcement of European powers: the reinforcement of European powers and their unification proved to be in capacity of stopping Viking raids, by two means: First, defending their coasts and cities, second recruiting Viking soldiers for their own use (Byzantine Empire did that for example).
- Second factor: Christianity and the reinforcement of Scandinavian kingdoms: these two factors proved very efficient in changing plundering raids into colonisation and/or trade-based migrations
- Third factor: The establishment of territories obtained from local kingdoms, such as Normandy or Sicily, proved also to be attractive for the Vikings, that had better life in going in a friendly-owned country and have a high social rank, rather than raiding

Comment: Counterpoint: Viking raids began while Charlemagne still ruled, personally, a highly-centralized government. That worked fine to defeat and Christianize the Saxons, but was totally inadequate at countering marine invaders who showed up on an hour's notice.  It was the increasingly **decentralized** responsibility for local defense as feudalism replaced Charlemagne's Empire that increasingly thwarted Viking raids. An Imperial army that mustered every Easter in Aachen was inadequate for sporadic coastal defense.

Comment: Having doubts about "the third factor" : are there documented cases of Scandinavian moving to the Viking kingdoms of Normandy or Sicily after they were settled, being friendly welcome and enjoying "a high social rank" there ?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Actually, reinforcement of power is not (always) synonym of centralized power, as well as unification is not entirely synonym of centralization.
Yes, Charlemagne's empire was not that good at repelling the viking, but the worst part of the raids in France (siege of Paris for example) came 4 to 5 generations after.
Harold was effective in repelling vikings

Comment: @Evargalo This comes from readings a long time ago, so I don't recall specific cases. But as I recall, yes Normandy and Sicily did expand with one group of Vikings establishing in a territory by "donation" under threat (e.g. Normandy) or capture, and more Vikings coming in